# Iterate generic collection top down (TDictionary)

Tags: delphi, sorting, collections, delphi-xe

I have a TDictionary. It's being filled with an extensive loop. When the loop finishes I need to retrieve the 10 keys(string) with more score(integer). What would be the most efficient way to accomplish this?

In Objective-C(Cocoa) I do it with:

```
NSArray *top_words_sorted_array = [top_words_dictionary keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

and then iterating the new sorted array. How can I do it in Delphi?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equivalent Delphi code to your Cocoa code is:

```
type
  TScorePair = TPair<string,Integer>;
var
  ScoresArray: TArray<TScorePair>;
....
ScoresArray := Scores.ToArray;
TArray.Sort(ScoresArray,
  TComparer<TScorePair>.Construct( 
    function(const L, R: TScorePair): Integer
    begin
      Result := R.Value - L.Value;
    end
  )
);
```

If your dictionary is very large then this will not be the most efficient solution. On the other hand, it's probably the quickest and easiest approach to implement.

Comment: Thank you David! It's as efficient as the original Obj-C code. The dictionary will go big but this code use is not frequent.

Comment: If the dictionary's really big, then you may not want to sort the whole list of values. You just need a *partial sort*. See the *selection algorithm* entry in Wikipedia, under [Selecting k smallest or largest elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Selecting_k_smallest_or_largest_elements)

Comment: Since when does TArray<T> have a Sort method?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to access it as a map (dictionary), or a plain array suffices?

If you must have it as a map, I would take a look at [DeHL.Collections](http://code.google.com/p/delphilhlplib/), perhaps `DeHL.Collections.DoubleSortedBidiMap` does what you need. The project page says it is discontinued but I use it everyday and never have a problem.

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://code.google.com/p/delphi-spring-framework/ which also has a powerful collection library and it's actively developed

Comment: I *think* the DeHL author is collaborating there.

Comment: Paul gave him commit rights but if I remember correctly Alex was not active in any form that I know of.